# Groups, if $ab = cd$ then $axb = cxd$ for all groups?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $ a,b,c,d,x ∈ G $ with $ a ≠ c , b ≠ d $

if $ ab = cd $ then $ axb = cxd $ for all groups?

Comment: Clearly that would be true for any abelian group.  Did you try any examples for non-abelian groups?

Comment: $rs=sr^{-1}$ but $r(r)s\neq s(r)r^{-1}$ where $r$ and $s$ are elements of $D_6$ (meaning the free group with relations $rs=sr^{-1}$, $r^3=s^2=e$)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions given fail to rule out a particularly trivial approach, which in fact works for monoids (semigroups with identity) as well as groups:

Suppose that for all $a,b,c,d,x\in G$ such that $a\ne c$, $b\ne d$, and $ab=cd$, $axb = cxd$.

Let $a=d=p$ and $b=c=e$, where $p$ is an arbitrary non-identity element and $e$ is the identity. Note that indeed $a\ne c$, $b\ne d$, and $ab=cd=p$.

Then for arbitrary $x$, $axb=cxd$, so $pxe=exp$, and thus $px=xp$. If $p=e$, then of course this holds as well. So $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Let $b = e$, the identity element. Then we have $a = cd$, which implies 
$$ad^{-1}c^{-1} = 1$$

Next, if we have

$$axb = cxd \Longrightarrow ax = cxd$$

We can take $x = a^{-1}$, so that

$$1 = ca^{-1}d$$

So that

$$ ad^{-1}a^{-1}d = (ad^{-1}c^{-1})(ca^{-1}d) = (1)(1) = 1$$

But if $ad^{-1}a^{-1}d = 1$, then $ad^{-1} = d^{-1}a$, so $a$ and $d^{-1}$ commute, so $a$ and $d$ commute.

So the question is: must $a$ and $d$ commute if $a = cd$? Surely not, for if $d$ and $a$ do not commute, we take $c = ad^{-1}$ and the above equation works.

Comment: So this shows not only that it is not always true, but that if it is true then the group must be abelian.

Comment: (In case anyone wants to read a proof that $a$ commuting with $d^{-1}$ implies that $a$ commutes with $d$: If $a$ and $d^{-1}$ commute, then $da=dad^{-1}d=dd^{-1}ad=ad$.)

Comment: Thanks Jonas! I just removed that when I realized my mistake. Thanks for the correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $b=c=1$, then $a=d$, so your claim implies that $ax=xd=xa$, which fails in nonabelian groups.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @dfeuer We do have the same argument, but with different levels of elaboration. I prefer succinctness over detail.